# Initialize same settings for a devexpress control in multiple forms

Tags: devexpress

I'm using the PropertyGrid control from DevExpress in multiple forms.
I have a ImageComboBoxEdit with the same settings (same ImageList, ItemList and multiple settings) on all of the forms.

I want all of them to have the same settings on the forms and don't want to go through all the forms to add a new option in the Combo.

What would be the best practices to implement this?
I've tried inheriting the RepositoryItem with limited success. Another idea would be to create a static helper class to initialize the default ImageComboBoxEdit with the right settings.

What would you prefer? Any other ideas?

Gunnar Steinn

Answer (score 1, accepted):

One more idea is to use the comboBox on a UserControl.  Thus, you will have to adjust it only once and then use this UserControl on as many forms as you want.

Comment: I didn't know that was possible. Can I use an UserControl as an editor for a propertygrid? Do you have a simple example?

Comment: I thought that you were going to use a standalone editor.  Since you want to use the same repositoryItem as a column editor in a grid and so on, this approach won't work.  If I were you, I would create a new static class which will return an instance of the required repositoryItem.

Comment: Thanks for the quick answer! I will implement it as a static class. I was hoping for a more elegant implementation but this will work :)